# Compare filenames in directory to string of Array

Tags: shell

I wanted to compare filenames in directory to strings in an array and echo not found and break if any one filename is not present - 
Code I wrote is

```
#!/bin/bash
# find all json files recursively;  cp to destination folder; try to parameterised/read from a file
#find  -name '*.json' -exec cp  {} destination_folder/ \; 

Dir2="destination_folder/*"

declare -a JSON_MandatoryFiles=('abc.json' 'bcd.json' 'efg.json' 'ijk.json');
for i in $Dir2; do

   for j in  "${JSON_MandatoryFiles[@]}";   do 
       if [ $j == $(basename $i) ]; then 
         echo $j "Found" 
         break
       fi
   done
done
```

However I'm unable to track where should I keep else echo "Not found" and break. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use :

```
Dir2="destination_folder" #remove /* from here

declare -a JSON_MandatoryFiles=('abc.json' 'bcd.json' 'efg.json' 'ijk.json');

for j in  "${JSON_MandatoryFiles[@]}";   do 
   if [ -f "${Dir2}/$j" ]; then 
     echo "$j exists"; 
   else 
     echo "$j does not exist"; # include exit; if you want to exit
fi
```

Comment: But this is giving me not found for every iteration check

Comment: Do one thing.. give absolute path for destination folder in DIR2 for eg. `DIR2="/home/abc/xyz"` (Don't put `/` at end of this as we are using `/` in `if` condition.

Comment: @RCoder: I've updated the solution !! Let me know if there is any issue.